# 'int' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, linked-list

So i've been trying to solve a problem in leetcode that is to design a linked list. Here's what i tried:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,next=None,val=None):
        self.next = next
        self.val = val

class Linked_list(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.length = 0

    def insertAtEnd(self, val):
        new_node = Node(val)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            itr = self.head
            while itr.next:     #Error
                itr = itr.next
            itr.next = new_node
            self.length += 1
```

So in the insertAtEnd method when i try to iterate over the list it shows the error that self.head is an an int object. I'm struggling to find an answer here. So please help me out. Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but I found one bug there

```
    new_node = Node(val)
```

But constructor looks:

```
    def __init__(self,next=None,val=None):
        self.next = next
        self.val = val
```

So you pass your **val** to **next** parameter and **self.head.next** points to **val** which is **int**. Probably you ment

```
    new_node = Node(val=val)
```

Or alternatively, change order of **next** and **val** in **Node** constructor.